# How many years to save x amount in order to retire, future value compound calculation

Tags: javascript, html

This is what i am trying to write javascript for. In order to solve for the years it would take to save "X" amount of dollars in order to retire. Logically this is solved via future value equation with a finance calculator or trial and error. Is there a cleaner way around this?

[image]
[image: enter image description her[![enter image description here]

```
    html>
    <head>
     <title></title>


   </head>


    <script>
     function calculate()
    {
            ra = document.getElementById("ra").value;   // amount needed 
  to retire
            p = document.getElementById("n").value;     // initial 
  investment
            t = document.getElementById("t").value;     // annual 
   contribution
            r = document.getElementById("rate").value; // radio button 
   interest rate



        }

    </script>


    <body>
    <h1>You probably want to retire someday so let's get started</h1>                    
   <br>
    <div> <label> How much money do you need to retire </label> <input 
    id="ra"> </div>      <br>
    <div> <label>Initial Investment </label> <input id="p"> </div>                       
    <br>
    <div> <label>Annual Contribution: </label> <input id="ac"> </div>                    
     <br>

    Expected Interest Rate: Select from the following please: <br>
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="1">   1  <br>
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="1.5"> 1.5<br>
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="2">   2  <br>
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="2.5"> 2.5<br>
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="3">   3  <br>
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="3.5"> 3.5<br>    
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="4">   4  <br>
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="4.5"> 4.5<br>
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="5">   5  <br>  
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="5.5"> 5.5<br>
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="6">   6  <br>
    <input type="radio" name="rate" value="6.5"> 6.5<br>




     <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>   
    <input type="button" value="Refresh Page" 
    onClick="window.location.reload()">

     <p id="result"> </p>
     display how many years it would take here
    </body>


    </html>
```

Comment: Instead of images add the your scripts and html!

Answer (score 0):

Since this scenario will apply compound interest,

```
Time (t) = ln(A/P) / r
where, A = final Amount
P = Principal
r = Interest Rate(R)/100
```

For your scenario -

```
document.getElementById("result).value = Math.log(ra/p)*100/r
```